# How to do Runge-Kutta with two coupled differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I want to apply the 4th order Runge-Kutta method on the [Lotka-Volterra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka-Volterra) equations, but how can I do that? Just do the steps, alternating between the two functions?

Comment: http://www.nsc.liu.se/~boein/f77to90/rk.html

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: OK, thanks! So basically, I was right, I just have to iterate through the functions, doing a step on each one? Hmm, that's actually pretty logical. Thanks! Mind submitting this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the comment by Riccardo Alestra: A system of two equations for functions $y,z$ can be thought of a single equation for a vector of dimension $2$, namely $(y,z)$. The formulas that constitute the Runge-Kutta method make just as much sense for vectors as for scalars. In fact, the Wikipedia article on [RK methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) says at the beginning:

> Here, $y$ is an unknown function (scalar or vector)