# ODE15s matlab function problem

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I have been trying to use the ODE15s built-in function of Matlab to solve the following system of equations:

$\frac{dy_{1}}{dt}=f_{1}\left(y_{1},y_{2}\right)$

$\frac{dy_{2}}{dt}=f_{2}\left(y_{1},y_{2}\right)$

where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are column vectors of size $(h,1)$, where $h$ is any integer. I tried several things but none worked. I would appreciate any ideas. I am beginning to think that this is impossible because the $y's$ are vectors rather than numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to write your equation as $\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y)$ where $y$ is a column vector of size $2h$, with the first $h$ entries being $y_1$ and the last $h$ entries being $y_2$? If yes, why didn't that work?

Comment: $f_1$ and $f_2$ are different so I don't think I can assemble them like that.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by assembling the vectors and the functions (according to the functions and the problem) and solved the problem. I don't think there is a way to solve this problem without making them all one.

Comment: Why is this question here, instead of a Matlab forum?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating the vectors $y_1$ and $y_2$ into one longer vector (and doing the same for functions) turns a system into a single equation for vector valued function. (As  Jitse Niesen said.) Matlab solvers expect you to do this conversion before invoking them. Related: [How to do Runge-Kutta with two coupled differential equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/116783/79365)